# Precendence contraint not working after keeping expression

Tags: ssis, operator-precedence

I have used two task connected to the foreach loop task, they both are executing and then foreach loop is executing after keeping contraint and expression it is not working.

Below is the sample scenerio:

[image]

Now I have created a variable:

```
istrue value: false
```

in one of the precendnce contraint I have kept @istrue == false and in other @istrue == true.

For both of the presedence constraints I have selected *Contraints & Expression*

But now it is not executing.. below is the what I am seeing now:

[image]

How to resolve this ?

Comment: I would say that one (or both) of your script tasks is not returning the value for the variable that you think it should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want foreach Loop cointainer to be executed if one of its precedence coinstraints will success set `Logical OR. One constaint must evaluate to True` in `Multiple constraint` section of one of them.
[image]